# boto3 variable with semicolon

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I've boto3 script which send emails to users. Please find an example as below:

```
**Variable1 = test1@gmail.com;test2@gmail.com**

**Variable2 = source@gmail.com**

**Variable3 = destination@gmail.com**

**response = ses.send_email(Source=[ Variable2 ], Destination={'ToAddresses': [ Variable1 ],'BccAddresses': [ Variable3 ]}, Message = message)**
```

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendEmail operation: Illegal semicolon, not in group"

Variable1 is email tag from Instances and some times have multiple emails separated by semicolon.

Comment: Split the semicolon-separated string into a *list* of addresses…?! Instead of passing a list with one string containing semicolon-separated addresses as `ToAddresses`…?!

Comment: I tried split, in one test case when there is only 1 email address ending with semicolon (test1@gmail.com;), it gave an error for second blank email address. right now I'm running by only selecting 1st email address like Variable1[0]

Comment: If you have single addresses ending in semicolons, you need to consider that case obviously. E.g., `trim` semicolons off the end, *then* split. Or split, then filter out empty strings from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split and filter out the valid e-mail addresses like this:

```
email_ids = list(filter(None, email_ids.split(";")))
```